# Can I customize the name of the open folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

when i use vscode remote ssh extension, I open an existing folder, dir is "/search/odin/lingxi/ec/trunk", name automatically become "trunk" , other folder dir is "/search/odin/lingxi/iq/trunk", name is "trunk" too, can i customize the name of the open folder?
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmczD.png)